# Passar dados do banco para um View no Adonisjs

Tags: javascript, adonisjs

Estou fazendo uma busca de um dado especifico no banco para retornar seus valores numa view (EdgeTemplate)

Porém na view mostra como **undefined**

**Minha rota**

```
Route.get('/atendimentos/:id_atendimento', 'AtendimentoController.show')
```

**Código do Controller**

```
 async show ({ params, request, response, view }) {
    const atendimento = await Atendimento.find(params.id_atendimento)

    return view.render('atendimento', {
      atendimento: atendimento
    })

  }
```

**Codigo da View**

```
@layout('layout.app')

@section('content')




  {{atendimento.nome_cliente}}



@endsection
```

Tem algo que esquecí?

Comment: no controller vc esta passando a váriavel `atendimento` ja tentou `atendimento.nome_cliente` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa converter o resultado em objeto JSON assim:

```
async show ({ params, request, response, view }) { const atendimento = await Atendimento.find(params.id_atendimento) return view.render('atendimento', { atendimento: atendimento.toJSON() }) }
```